# Javascript переменная

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает? как можно так передавать параметры?

onclick="LoadGifts('love')"

он их не принимает.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
   var gifts;
    function LoadGifts(gifts) {

  // Отсылаем паметры
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",url: "gifts.php",
                data: "gifts="+gifts,
                // Выводим то что вернул PHP
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
 //предварительно очищаем нужный элемент страницы
$("#gifts_load").css("display", "");
$("#gifts_load").empty();
$("#gifts_load").append(html);
$("#gifts_load").fadeIn(800);
 }
        });
}
</script>

<div style="float:left"><form id="form" name="form" method="post">
<img src="img/love.png" style="padding-left:10px;" border="0" onclick="LoadGifts('love')"></div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img/friend.png" style="padding-left:10px;" border="0" onclick="LoadGifts('friend')"></div>
<img src="img/happy.png" style="padding-left:10px;" border="0" onclick="LoadGifts('happy')"></form>
<div id="gifts_load" class="gifts_load"></div>
```

Comment: путь у php файлу правильно прописан?

Comment: @big-vl, зачем вы всё в кашу превратили? HTML - отдельно, CSS и JS так же по отдельным файлам раскидайте. Если используете jQuery, то зачем мешать с чистым JS, который так же логичней будет прописывать не внутри html-тэгов, а в отдельном файле или соответствующем ему тэге <script>. В консоле проверяли? Отправляются данные и приходит ответ? В ответе есть какие-то ошибки? Зачем использовать "очистку блока", а потом метод append(), если достаточно использовать метод html(), который заменит всё содержимое блока на новый контент. И [пример для раздумий][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/6pxMG